# jpa project problem in hibernate console configuration

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa

when i create a jpa project under eclipse, i encoutered the following problem: when i create the a configuration file, i check creat console, next when i specify jpa as **type** in the **main** tab of the **Console Configuration Wizard**, i get the error message in the top of the wizard:
[image]

how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create Persistence unit first check this link http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Persistence+Unit